# Can't find Sample Watch faces in AVD

Tags: android, watch-face-api

I am trying to learn how to create Android Wear watch faces.  The problem that I am having is I can't see any of the sample watch faces in the emulator.  How do I get the samples into the emulator so I can see the changes I make?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Debug your watch face project with AndroidStudio and make sure the emulator has finished initialization(Can see the default watch face).Then keep the emulator running and debug or run your watch face project again with the same emulator,you can see the install watch face log,long press the emulator you may see your watch face.